# Thread safe LRU cache implementation

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a requirement to create a thread safe LRU cache. I don't want to reinvent the wheel but am looking for a simple solution. I had a look at apache LRU but that doesn't provide safety in a multi-threaded environment. I can write my own implementation using `LinkedHashMap` with lock strategy but just wanted to check if we have any out of the box solution available.

Comment: Guava [`CacheBuilder`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained). You can also use a `LinkedHashMap` with the `removeEldestEntry` overridden and add your own thread safety fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at Cacheonix open source cache at [www.cacheonix.com](http://www.cacheonix.com). It's has a local cache mode wich is completely thread-safe. I'm the developer, so I'll be happy to answer any questions you have.

Regards,

Slava Imeshev